# Is it possible to Left-Align headers in a WPF TabControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, tabcontrol

Right now, I have a WPF window where all the tab labels of the `TabControl` are centered.

I'd like the tab levels of the `TabControl` to be left-aligned.

Is this possible without completely redoing the `ControlTemplate`?

I tried messing with `HorizontalAlignment`, `HorizontalContentAlignment`, etc., but nothing I tried had the desired effect.

If I try this solution (offered by T Levesque):

```
<TabControl...>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

...I get this:

All the tab labels of the `TabControl` are left-aligned, but the tabs don't stretch properly

Which is close, but it ends up looking kind of like a histogram.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following will give you the look you are after.

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
        <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Header="Header 1">
            <TabItem.Content>Test</TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Header="Header 2"  >
            <TabItem.Content>Test</TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Header="Header Longer Version">
            <TabItem.Content>Test</TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: I just tested, and came up with something with the correct look.

Answer (score 4):

What sort of Control are you using for the TabItem.Header property? If you are simply using a Label, are you specifying the width of the Label to some common value? If the Label is sizing to content then it will appear as you have shown. Try the following with a common width for the labels used to display the header text:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" >
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Width="100">test tab 1</Label>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            xyz
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Width="100">test t2</Label>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            abc
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Width="100">test tab three</Label>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            abc
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define the horizontal alignment for all tab headers :

```
<TabControl...>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't quite work. I edited my question to show what this does.

Comment: But +1 for the idea of setting the `ItemContainerStyle`...saves a lot of markup. See my second edit.

Answer (score 3):

Simply adding the attribute HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" to the TabControl will align tab headers left.

```
<TabControl
Margin="0,5,0,0"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
TabStripPlacement="Left">
<TabItem
    Header="Perform System Administration">
    ...
<TabItem
    Header="Perform Setup Tasks">
    ...
```